# Feel like a sore thumb

Tags: meaning

In the film, someone walks through a suburb while speaking to a friend on the phone, saying, "I feel like a sore thumb out here."

I found the meaning of "stand/stick out like a sore thumb" on the internet, but I'm not sure if this expression has the same meaning.

Comment: "Feel like" is not the set expression. It's a reference to *your* expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No doubt he means "I feel as though I must stick out like a sore thumb", i.e. look conspicuous.